# MPMoviePlayerController dismisses my UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an iPhone app where I load an `UIImagePickerController` onto a `UIViewController`. I then have a custom view on top of the camera. Now when the user takes a photo it is loaded onto a `UIImageView` which presents it to the user asking if you want to use that photo or take another (removing the image from the `UIImageView`). This works perfectly.

Now If the user has just recorded a video I wanted to take a snapshot preview somewhere in the video and present it as a static image in the same `UIImageView`. I do this with the following code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
[videoPlayer setContentURL:[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];

UIImage *videoScreenShot = [videoPlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:(videoPlayer.duration/2.0) timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
photoPreview.image = videoScreenShot;
[videoPlayer release]
```

This works as intended. The problem is if I want to take another video. When I call:

`[videoPlayer setContentURL:[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];`

The camera shutter closes and the camera is seemingly dismissed. Trying to take a picture or recording video gives me:

```
UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to take picture; camera is not yet ready.
UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to start video capture; camera is not yet ready.
```

I've tried calling the following after, which has no effect:

```
myImagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];  
[myImagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
```

I tried adding the `UIImagePickerController` to the `UIIViewController` again, which caused some fantastic freeze-ups.

Finally I tried commenting out the `UIViewController's` `[super didReceivedMemoryWarning]` line of `didReceivedMemoryWarning`. Which also had no effect.

I'm guessing `MPMoviePlayerController` takes over something `UIImagePicker` also needs. How do I give it back?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting your MPMoviePlayerController to nil before showing the UIImagePickerController, or maybe taking its view out of the interface temporarily. Both of these contain a movie player view, but there can be only one movie player view at a time in your application's interface. Thus they can interfere with each other, and that might be what's happening to you.